# How do I mount the /dev/sda partition from CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso?

Tags: centos, iso

I need some help figuring out how to mount partition 1 (xfs, boot) of the /dev/sda device from CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso on a CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) VM. There are multiple devices in the image. This partition is in the second device. The first device is the ISO image itself.

#### Some system info

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 9 14:09:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ whoami
root
```

This is what I have done so far.

#### Step 1. Download and verify the ISO

```
$ wget http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/7.2.1511/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso
<output snipped>
$ ls -l CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jlinoff jlinoff 632291328 Dec  9 15:03 CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso
$ md5sum CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso 
88c0437f0a14c6e2c94426df9d43cd67  CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso
$ # matches 88c0437f0a14c6e2c94426df9d43cd67 from http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/7.2.1511/isos/x86_64/md5sum.txt
```

#### Step 2. View the available devices using parted

```
$ parted CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso print devices
/home/jlinoff/work/iso/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso (632MB)
/dev/sda (21.5GB)
/dev/mapper/centos-swap (2147MB)
/dev/mapper/centos-root (18.8GB)
/dev/sr0 (59.0MB)
```

#### Step 3. View the partitions

```
$ parted CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso select /dev/sda unit B print
Using /dev/sda
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 21474836480B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start       End           Size          Type     File system  Flags
 1      1048576B    525336575B    524288000B    primary  xfs          boot
 2      525336576B  21474836479B  20949499904B  primary               lvm
```

#### Step 4. Mount partition 1 based on the offset

```
$ mkdir -m 0777 /tmp/foo
$ mount -t xfs -o loop,ro,offset=1048576 CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso /tmp/mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

#### Step 5. Try to figure out the correct offset

It seemed obvious that the offset was wrong so I tried to figure it out based on the preceding filesystem by incorporating the endpoint from the previous device:

```
$ parted CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.img select /home/jlinoff/work/iso/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.img unit B print
Using /home/jlinoff/work/iso/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.img
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/jlinoff/work/iso/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.img: 632291328B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start    End       Size      Type     File system  Flags
 2      196608B  6615039B  6418432B  primary

$ bc
1048576 + 6615039
7663615
```

I tried offset=7663615 and offset=6615039. Same error.

This is the full list of all devices.

```
$ parted CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso unit B print all
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
Model:  (file)
Disk /home/jlinoff/work/iso/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso: 632291328B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start    End       Size      Type     File system  Flags
 2      196608B  6615039B  6418432B  primary


Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 21474836480B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start       End           Size          Type     File system  Flags
 1      1048576B    525336575B    524288000B    primary  xfs          boot
 2      525336576B  21474836479B  20949499904B  primary               lvm


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 2147483648B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End          Size         File system     Flags
 1      0B     2147483647B  2147483648B  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 18756927488B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End           Size          File system  Flags
 1      0B     18756927487B  18756927488B  xfs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The iso is not formatted as XFS... I'm sure it wouldn't be.

Comment: Right, that makes sense but I was hoping that the /dev/sda device was just the raw bytes which might be formatted as XFS and that I could access it by using the appropriate offset. Can you think of another way to extract that data without mounting the ISO and installing the OS?

Answer (score 1):

`losetup(8)` has an option (`-P` or `--partscan`) that can scan for partitions inside an image file and then actually map them to virtual block devices, so that instead of this:

```
$ losetup -a
/dev/loop0: []: yourisoimage.iso
```

...you will be able to see additional loop devices referring to partitions:

```
$ ls /dev/loop*
/dev/loop0
/dev/loop0p1
/dev/loop0p2
/dev/loop-control
```

Use the following command to automatically allocate a new `loopX` device and scan for additional partitions:

```
$ losetup -f -P yourisoimage.iso
```

Then just mount the corresponding loop *device* without the `-o loop` mount option.

---

**EDIT**: after reading your comment below, I think some clarifications are in order.

---

What I think is going on here is you're looking for a rabbit in the hen-house.

What you are seeing in the second step above is the list of *all* devices in the system, not just a list of partitions on the ISO file. Your command includes a bogus parameter (the name of the ISO file) and `parted` is just listing every partition it sees on any device.

What you are probably actually trying to do is to mount `/dev/sda2` off the *physical* disk `/dev/sda` which has absolutely nothing to do with that CentOS ISO file.

Furthermore, since that partition is not a filesystem partition but rather a *physical volume* (of LVM fame), there is no filesystem present directly on it.

To be able to access its contents, you should use `pvscan` to discover all physical volumes in the system, `vgchange -ay` to activate all volume groups, and then `vgs` and `lvs` to see the list of volume groups and logical volumes.

The contents are accessed under a special name which reads `/dev/<vgname>/<lvname>`, so for a volume group named `foo`, and a logical volume named `bar`, the name would be `/dev/foo/bar`.

What you mount is hence `/dev/foo/bar` and not `/dev/sda2`.

Comment: That is a great idea but it doesn't work for devices other than the first one (home/jlinoff/work/iso/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511.iso) in this case. You can see what losetup will create by running `fdisk -l`.